Over Achieved vs. Overachieved
Can these be spelled both ways? Or overachieved is the only correct way?

Do you have a preference for US or British English ?

Why do you want to? You can't just detach prefixes or break up words. On this site you are required to show your working, e.g. what research you have done. On the other hand there are contexts where "over achieved" is valid, "The boy who just came over achieved a high score in his test".

What does this have to do with pronunciation or grammar?

Upvoting such questions is against the spirit of the site. As Stuart implies, and many others have done over the years. Can 'over achieve/d' be found as an alternative spelling in any dictionary?
